# CallableStatement registerOutParameter with OracleTypes.ARRAY taking too long

Tags: jdbc, java-8, ojdbc, oracle19c

We are using Oracle Table Types in fetching data from Oracle 19C database using Java 8 (ojdbc8.jar) JDBC callable Statement, when trying to register an out parameter is taking approximately 7-8 seconds.

```
logger.info("Trying to set 12th parameter");
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(12, OracleTypes.ARRAY,"AASC_SERIAL_NUMBERS_TBL"); // taking 7-8 seconds  time
logger.info("Completed setting 12th parameter");
```

Below is the syntax of record type:

```
create or replace TYPE "AASC_SERIAL_NUMBERS_TBL" is table of AASC_SERIAL_NUMBERS_rec;
```

```
create or replace TYPE "AASC_SERIAL_NUMBERS_REC" is object
(DELIVERY_ID number,
DELIVERY_DETAIL_ID number,
SERIAL_CONTROL_CODE number,
LOT_CONTROL_CODE number,
SUBINVENTORY varchar2(200),
locator varchar2(200),
LOT_NUMBER varchar2(200),
SERIAL_NUMBER varchar2(200),
SERIAL_LIST varchar2(32767),
SHIPMENT_LINE_ID NUMBER);
```

The same code is taking less than 1 second with Oracle 12C database with same Java 8 and ojdbc8 drivers.
We want to understand what exactly is happening when we call **registerOutParameter** and why Oracle 19C database is taking time to respond at this specific step.

Comment: For sure you will have to fetch some type metadata, which is probable the problem.  Standard way: check for patches, contact Oracle support...

Comment: We have contacted Oracle support for their inputs on this issue and since it is from Java custom application they replied saying it is out of scope of support.

Comment: Which version of the Oracle JDBC driver are you using (and no, ojdbc8 is not a version of the driver, it just means the driver is for Java 8).

Comment: I've verified the ojdbc8.jar and the MANIFEST.MF file shows Specification-Version: 4.2.